# Declare the Function vs Declaration

Tags: javascript

Why do people say "declare the function" when only statements with let, const, or var are declarations? I also get confused because the name of one type of function is a function declaration.

Comment: sorta related (not dupe-marking b/c this is JS, and that's C): https://stackoverflow.com/q/1410563/1757964

Answer (score 0):

is that more clear?

```
const myFunction = function (a,b) {  return a+b; }

console.log ( myFunction (5,10) );   // 15
console.log ( myFunction (25,30) );  // 55
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

Javascript developers will often use the terms "function declaration" and "function definition" interchangeably. In some languages these are separate concepts (e.g. C); in Javascript they are not.

Probably when a JS developer says "declare the function" what they mean is "put the function *here* so you can call it over *there*."

...

However, so I don't get downvoted to oblivion:

Technically, in Javascript, *this* is a function declaration:

```
function foo(bar) {
  // function body goes here
}
```

Whereas *this* is a function expression (and also a variable declaration):

```
const foo = function() {
  // function body goes here
};
```

Both can be called in the usual way. The results are *almost* identical, except that the function declaration is hoisted and the const declaration is not.

See here for more on the difference:
https://medium.com/@mandeep1012/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions-b43646042052